# How do I have a confirmation notice appear when I click send via the webapp?

Tags: google-apps-script, button, send

When I click a Send Button, the data gets sent to the email, but I do not see a notification indicating it worked. I only know it worked when checking my email. I want to know how to have a window pop up showing that it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [window.alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) or [window.prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) on the clientside.  On the server checkout the [UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)  and there's also `Spreadsheet.toast()` for a little popup on the right hand lower corner of the spreadsheet.

I like to use some thing this when issuing commands using google.script.run.

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){window.alert('I have completed the command and returned back from the server.')}).servercommand();
```